# How can I open password protected ODS files (Open Office)?

Tags: openoffice

Found many Open Office viewer apps, but couldn't find a password protected ODS viewer ... I wonder why it was not ported yet - it is open source so it would be just an issue of converting existing code.

ODS password protection is by far a lot better than XLS password protection.

If anyone knows of an app or some other method I would be grateful :)

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) is currently [being ported to Android](http://www.phonearena.com/news/LibreOffice-coming-to-Android_id31986). It's reported they are making good progress, but I couldn't find any planned due-date yet. According to the article linked, they focus on having a viewer ready soon, and add the "tons of features" later to make it a full-featured office app. See also [here](http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/258834/libreoffice_for_android_is_in_the_works.html) for the original source, including some screenshots.

Apart from that, there seems no app currently available to effectively handle OpenDocument. True, there are tons of office apps on the market/playstore, but they all stick with the MS formats. Which leaves us to hope for LibreOffice coming soon to the Play Store...